# To find a conditional probability of two events from given information

Tags: probability, probability-theory

> If $E$ and $F$ are events such that $P(E)=a, P(F|E)=P(\overline{F}|\overline{E})=1-a$. Then find $P(\overline{E}|F)$ as an expression that does not involve $a$.

This is an exercise from class. I am guessing they want us to show that $P(\overline{F}|E)$ is independent of $a\ (=P(E))$. Here is what I have been up to.

I feel based on the information they have provided we need to apply Bays theorem

$$ P(\overline{E}|F) = \frac{P(F|\overline{E})P(\overline{E})}{P(F|\overline{E})P(\overline{E})+P(F|E)P(E)}.$$

From here substituting what we know,

$$ P(\overline{E}|F) = \frac{P(F|\overline{E})(1-a)}{P(F|\overline{E})(1-a)+a(1-a)}.$$

I am not getting how to proceed from here. Any help would be great!

Comment: I'm guessing that the bar means complement?

Comment: @carmichael561 Yes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $\mathbb{P}(\overline{F}\mid\overline{E})=1-a$, it follows that $$\mathbb{P}(F\mid\overline{E})=1-\mathbb{P}(\overline{F}\mid\overline{E})=1-(1-a)=a$$

and so your expression simplifies to $\frac{1}{2}$.